# React Router how to redirect path to path with query params and multiple query params to same component?

Tags: react-router

I have a component called `TableComponent`. I want to redirect path `tables/:table` to `tables/:table?tab=tab1` and all different tabs use the same `TableComponent`.
For example:

`tables/:table?tab=tab1` -> `TableComponent`

`tables/:table?tab=tab2` -> `TableComponent`

`tables/:table?tab=tab3` -> `TableComponent`

I have the code below but it doesn't work:

```
<Redirect
  exact
  from="/tables/:table"
  to={{
    pathname: "/tables/:table",
    search: "?tab=tab1"
  }}
/>
<Route
  path="/tables/:table" <- how can I make this route ignore the query params?
  component={TableComponent}
  />
```

Or should i do the redirect inside the `TableComponent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited:**

Add a parent component above the Table Component and check if there are query params in the URL using React Router's useHistory. If there are none, use the useHistory hook and do history.push(tables/:table?tab=tab1).

**Original answer**:

I don't think you need the redirect. Use the route to take you to the TableComponent.

```
<Route
  path="/tables/:table"
  component={TableComponent}
  />
```

When the user clicks a link that should direct to a certain tab, add the query param to the URL, like so:

```
<Link to={`tables/${table}?tab=${tab}`}
```

The URL would be something like `tables/august-finances?tab=1` or whatever.

In the tables component, use the `useHistory` hook to see if there's a search parameter and what it is. This is a built-in prop of the hook. Anything after the `?` in the URL will be viewable from history.

Ex.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react;
import { useHistory } from 'react-router;

const TableComponent = () => {
// create state for the tab and set it to null 
const [tab, setTab] = useState(null);

let history = useHistory(); 

useEffect(() => {
// this will be `tab=tab1`
const queryString = history.search; 

//isolate the tab by splitting the string by the = character
// it will create array ["tab","tab1"], get the "tab1"
const currentTab = queryString.split("=")[1];
setTab(currentTab);
},[history]);


return(
// if !tab, return nothing 
// if tab does have a value, use a conditional expression to return which tab of the table should be shown first
)
}
```

Comment: yeah i'm using "no redirect" right now (clicking each tab will choose corresponding query parameter) similar to what u did except i'm getting the query parameters from useQuery hook https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters.

However, i'd like to know if there is a way to make the url shown that the component starts at the first tab (make the url and tab consistent).

Comment: @eriee Oh like `tables/:table` --> `tables/:table?tab=tab1`? Add a parent component above the Table Component and check if there are query params in the URL. If there are none, use the useHistory hook and do history.push(tables/:table?tab=tab1). I will edit my answer if this comment is unclear.

Comment: yeah i put the history.push inside the TableComponent then. Can you add the comment to your answer? Thanks